# 呼び出したいplistの名前の部分を動的に決めさせたい

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

iPhoneアプリ作成中です。
plistを呼び出す際に、タップした画像ごとに別のplistを呼び出させて、plistの中身をtableViewで
表示させようとしています。条件と手順は以下の通りです。

・画像（名前：photo01〜10)と、plist(名前：photo01〜10)を用意します。
・画像photo01〜10は、Aisatuクラスにコレクションビューで並べてあります。
・タップした画像の名前を取得して、取得した画像の名前と同じ名前の
　plistを呼び出そうとしています。

そこで、

```
// 上のクラス（Aisatuクラス)のインスタンスを取得する
NSUInteger idx = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] indexOfObject: self] - 1;
Aisatu *masterVC = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex: idx];


// タップした画像のインデックスを算出する※detailItemの型はid型です。
NSUInteger nextImageIdx = [masterVC.photos[0] indexOfObject: self.detailItem];

NSString *st=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)nextImageIdx];


NSString* dataFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:st
                                                    ofType:@"plist"];
arrayList = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:dataFile];
```

と書いてみたのですが、うまくいきません。

NSUInteger nextImageIdx = [masterVC.photos[0] indexOfObject: self.detailItem];
のところがうまくいっていないようなのですが、原因がわかりません。

どのようにすれば良いのかご教示いただけないでしょうか。
以上、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NSUInteger nextImageIdx = [masterVC.photos[0] indexOfObject:
>   self.detailItem]; のところがうまくいっていないようなのですが、原因がわかりません。

「うまくいって」いるかどうかは、NSLog()で出力すれば、すぐにわかります。

```
NSLog(@"nextImageIdx = %lu", nextImageIdx);
```

Property Listのファイル名が、「photo01.plist」、「photo02.plist」……となっているのなら、

```
NSString *st=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"photo%02lu",(unsigned long)nextImageIdx];


NSString* dataFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:st
                                                    ofType:@"plist"];
```

こうなると思います。NSLog()や、NSStringのメソッド「stringWithFormat:」の変換記号（%luなど）の仕様は、C言語のprintf()に準じます。空き桁を0で埋め、2桁で出力するオプションは「%02lu」となります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。idxの値を取得するときにトラブルがあるようです。どんな画像をタップしてもidxのログを取ると「１」しか出てきません。

Comment: プロパティリスト取得とは、無関係のトラブルですね？問題点を整理し、だれにもわかるような文章にして、新規に質問なさってはいかがですか？

Comment: そうですね。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* dataFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:name
                                                ofType:@"plist"];
```

で、いけるでしょ。nameを、あなたが、正しく提供できるならば。

Comment: ご回答いただいておいてすみません、質問内容を大幅に変更しました。